# How to mock Exception for ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, junit

I have one two-line method for writing string as a byte array. Here is code for that.
Now I want to write one test case to cover IOException.

```
public void convertStr(String str) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream io = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            io.write(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
    }
```

I am only able to write a test for the string but not able to produce exception.

```
@Test
    public void test2() throws IOException {
        convertStr("exception");
        assertTrue(true);
    }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to test a scenario that can not happen.

`ByteArrayOutputStream.write(byte[])` will never throw an `IOException` - it's a method inherited from OutputStream which simply delegates to [`ByteArrayOutputStream.write(byte[],int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#write(byte%5B%5D,int,int))

I would suggest changing the code you're trying to test to

```
io.writeBytes(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

so that you don't have to add code to catch an exception that is never thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mocking API such as `Mockito`

```
Mockito.when(mockedObj.myMethod(Matchers.anyString()).thenThrow(new IOException("Error"));
```